# how to call? when i have same element name from 2 different forms within 1 page

Tags: jquery

here is the situation.

1. i have 2 forms (formA, formB) in 1 page
2. both forms having a input element with using same name='ClientID' (which dynamic generate base on database.
3. so far i can different form with my jquery code below.

   ```
   $("form[name='FormA']").submit(function(){
       alert("FormA");
   });
   $("form[name='FormB']").submit(function(){
       alert("FormB");
   });
   ```
4. so now under both forms hava a input element like

   ```
   <input type='text' name='ClientID' value=''>
   ```
5. and now how i call FormA ClientID or FormB ClientID ? something like ...

   ```
   $("form[name='FormA']").submit(function(){
       $(this + ":input[name='ClientID']).val(); ???
   });
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("form[name='FormA']").submit(function(){
    $("input[name='ClientID']", this).val();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, using [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method:

```
$("form[name='FormA']").submit(function() {
    var value = $(this).find("input[name='ClientID']").val();
});
```

Comment: oh yes, thanks for guide, i learn something new now, but sample below is more like my style. anyway, i also just learn "find" from you.